# APScheduler not remembering jobs after Heroku sleeps

Tags: python, heroku, sqlalchemy, apscheduler

I am currently trying to implement APScheduler through Heroku. I have the scheduler working through Heroku with Python just as expected when the Heroku is running. The issue I am running into is when the Heroku dyno goes to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity. I want to be able to make Heroku active again and have the scheduler remember all of the jobs that were not triggered before it went to sleep. I am using the `SQLAlchemyJobStore` which is supposed to remember jobs after the scheduler is shut down.

Here is the code that I am using currently:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore

jobstores = {
    'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')
}
job_defaults = {
    'coalesce': False,
    'max_instances': 1
}

sched = BlockingScheduler()
sched.configure(jobstores=jobstores, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone='America/New_York')

def my_job(text):
    print(text)

def add_jobs():
    print("scheduling")
    sched.add_job(my_job, 'date', run_date='2019-7-17 15:25:00', args=['date job firing'], id = "Job1", misfire_grace_time = 18000)
    sched.add_job(my_job, 'date', run_date='2019-7-17 15:30:00', args=['date to run'], id = "Job2", misfire_grace_time=18000)
    sched.add_job(my_job, 'date', run_date='2019-7-17 16:30:00', args=['job after shutdown'], id = 'Job3', misfire_grace_time = 18000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_jobs()
    #sched.print_jobs()
    sched.start()
```

In this case, I commit and push the code to heroku, which runs this file in heroku. The results I get are as followed:

```
2019-07-17T19:24:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user
2019-07-17T19:25:03.445241+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: State changed from down to starting
2019-07-17T19:25:03.227462+00:00 app[api]: Release v268 created by user 
2019-07-17T19:25:03.227462+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 6d599479 by user
2019-07-17T19:25:09.364735+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: Starting process with command `python clock.py`
2019-07-17T19:25:10.118949+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-07-17T19:25:13.928223+00:00 app[clock.1]: scheduling
2019-07-17T19:25:14.142912+00:00 app[clock.1]: date job firing
2019-07-17T19:25:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-07-17T19:30:00.051064+00:00 app[clock.1]: date to run
```

30 minutes after the the previous job triggered, Heroku sleeps. This is when I ping Heroku to wake up and then the last job at 16:30:00 does not trigger at the time it should.

I believe the issue might have to do with the database. I am not sure what is in the database at any certain time or if the scheduler is pulling the non executed jobs every time Heroku goes to sleep.

If anyone knows why this is happening that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an SQLite database to store your jobs. This doesn't play nicely with Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), which loses all changes every time your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day) and likely occurs when your app sleeps and then wakes back up.

You should use a client-server database instead. Heroku's [Postgres service](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) might be a better choice. It's supported out of the box and the base plan is free.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was wondering if you had an example or something because Im not quite sure how to connect the database with the scheduler.